# How to prove convergence to $1-\frac{1}{\log(n)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers

I am trying to prove that:

$$\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{4}{5}\left(...+\frac{p_{m-2}-1}{p_{m-2}}\left(\frac{1}{p_{m-1}}+\frac{p_{m-1}-1}{p_{m-1}}\left(\frac{1}{p_{m}}\right)\right)...\right)\right)\right)\right)\approx1-\frac{1}{\log(n)}$$

Where $m=\pi(\sqrt{n})$

Some help would be really welcomed! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `$\log$` for $\log$ instead of `$log$` for $log$.

Comment: $m=\pi(\sqrt{n})$? $m$ should be an integer?

Comment: @MartinRosenau I think $\pi(\cdot)$ is the [prime counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function).

Comment: I don't understand what is the LHS. Are you trying to estimate the probability that $n$ is not prime ? Then assuming a probability distribution such that $Pr[n \not \equiv 0 \bmod p_j, j \in 1 \ldots J] \approx \prod_{j=1}^J Pr[ n \not \equiv 0 \bmod p_j] \approx \prod_{j=1}^J (1-\frac{1}{p_j})$ then $Pr[n$ is not prime $] = 1-Pr[n$ is prime $]=1-\prod_{ p \le \sqrt{n}} Pr[ n \not \equiv 0 \bmod p] \approx 1- \prod_{ p \le \sqrt{n}} (1-\frac{1}{p})$. That the last expression is $\approx 1-\frac{1}{\log n}$ is quite equivalent to the [PNT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem)

Comment: Thanks for your format advice @Shaun; it is already fixed.

Comment: @MartinRosenau, as already commented, $\pi(\sqrt{n})$ is the prime counting function.

Comment: @reuns, thanks a lot for your comment; indeed, I knew that the assertion is quite equivalent to the PNT, so I was looking for some way to prove the convergence to $1-\frac{1}{\log(n)}$ and bound it without using the PNT.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that Merten's third theorem, which remarkably can be proved without the assistance of the Prime Number Theorem, establishes that:

$\lim_{x\to \infty}\log{(x)}\prod_{p\le{x}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)=e^{-\gamma}$

Using this theorem, the proof I was looking for follows easily.